# HERE geocode API latinized address

Tags: here-api

I've noticed quite severe inconsistency in result provided by HERE /geocode API endpoint. Some address parts have original special characters like in "Łódź" city and some don't.

When doing following request:
`https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?lon=19.4734111&lat=51.73771300000001&language=sv-SE&searchtext=sienkiewicza lodz&result_types=address,place&cs=pds&additionaldata=Country2,true`

We get the result which is inconsistent

`"Address": {
    "Label": "ulica Henryka Sienkiewicza, 90-009 Lodz, Polen",
    "Country": "POL",
    "State": "Woj. Łódzkie",
    "County": "Lodz",
    "City": "Lodz",
    "District": "Lodz",
    "Subdistrict": "Śródmieście",
    "Street": "ulica Henryka Sienkiewicza",
    "PostalCode": "90-009",
    "AdditionalData": [
        {
            "value": "PL",
            "key": "Country2"
        },
        {
            "value": "Polen",
            "key": "CountryName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Woj. Łódzkie",
            "key": "StateName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Lodz",
            "key": "CountyName"
        }
     ]
}`

As we can see value for state contains polish characters "Woj. Łódzkie", but city is "Lodz" which is not ok.

All results should contain original letters like "Łódź". In other words such results shouldn't be latinized. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When using a language code different than the one of the original data, like in your case sv-SE for data in Poland, you get exonyms "where available", which is why you may get a mix of alphabets.

If you remove the `language` parameter from the query, or set it to Polish explicitely with `language=pl-PL`, you get the following response for your example:

```
"Address": {
    "Label": "ulica Henryka Sienkiewicza, 90-057 Łódź, Polska",
    "Country": "POL",
    "State": "Woj. Łódzkie",
    "County": "Łódź",
    "City": "Łódź",
    "District": "Łódź",
    "Subdistrict": "Śródmieście",
    "Street": "ulica Henryka Sienkiewicza",
    "PostalCode": "90-057",
    "AdditionalData": [
        {
            "value": "PL",
            "key": "Country2"
        },
        {
            "value": "Polska",
            "key": "CountryName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Woj. Łódzkie",
            "key": "StateName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Łódź",
            "key": "CountyName"
        }
    ]
}
```